# Using dynamic programming to compute an integer sequence

Tags: number-theory, difference-equations, integer-sequence

Let a[n] = n + 1 - a[EulerPhi[n]], n integer > 0. I have Python code that generates the sequence using dynamic programming. How can I achieve the same thing elegantly/idiomatically in Mathematica?

This is my Python code:

```
from sympy import totient as phi

N = 100

# a(n) = n + 1 - a(phi(n)), n > 0

a = [ 0 ] * N

# a(1) = 1 + 1 - a(phi(1)) = 2 - a(1) => 2 a(1) = 2 => a(1) = 1

a[1] = 1

# a(n), n > 1 computed using dynamic programming

for n in range(2, N):
    a[n] = n + 1 - a[phi(n)]

print(a[1:])
```

Comment: a[1] = 1;
a[n_] := n + 1 - a[EulerPhi[n]]; Or to speed it up: a[n_] := a[n]= n + 1 - a[EulerPhi[n]];

Comment: Thanks! So I forgot the _. :/ Is it possible to use RecurrenceTable[]? I'm not really going for speed. And do I really have to define a[1]? That looks inelegant to me.
Edit: turns out I don't have to define a[1]. I was hoping I wouldn't have to.

Comment: My current solution is "a[n_] := n + 1 - a[EulerPhi[n]]; Table[a[n], {n , 1, 20}]" but that's just procedural and ugly. Can it be done using functional style programming as a one liner? Sorry, my mathematica knowledge is abysmal. :/

Comment: I promise that I will delete this question if someone gives me a nice one liner. It's for OEIS.

Comment: As `EulerPhi[n]<n` for `n>1` , your formula is a recurrence. So it needs a recurrence stop for `n==1`. You could make a one liner using an Ìf`` for the case `n==1`, but that I would consider this ugly coding.

Comment: @DanielHuber It really doesn't tho. Mathematica is clever enough to figure out that a(1) = 1 + 1 - a(phi(1)) = 2 - a(1) => 2 a(1) = 2 => a(1) = 1. Python is not, which is why I had to define a[1] to be 1.
Edit: No, you're right. It really seems like I need to explicitly define a[1].

Comment: Which is funny because the procedural version works fine without the anchor. Try this: "a[n_] := n + 1 - a[EulerPhi[n]]; Table[a[n], {n , 1, 20}]". I'm just too inept to leverage that into a 1-liner.

Comment: **I think your obsession with a one-liner is counterproductive**. For instance, if I had to read the version provided by Daniel Huber versus the version provided by kglr, I would find the recursive version much clearer. The one liner would qualify as obfuscated code in my opinion.

Comment: @MarcoB Well, I agree. In this case tho, we're literally talking about a column in a db. The people at OEIS actually reprimanded me for providing 100 terms of my integer sequence. 70 terms was acceptable. Code for generating sequences is just another column with similar byte size restrictions. This is why I asked for a 1-liner.

Comment: @Emanuel I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: It does feel bad tho. In the best of all possible worlds, OEIS would accept a Jupyter or Mathematica notebooks. OEIS is a fantastic resource, but it's stuck in the 1990:s. :/

Comment: I think you are fooling yourself if you claim that MMA works without a recurrence stop. Start a new kernel and try again. I think `a[1]` was already defined without you noticing.

Comment: @DanielHuber I did exactly that yesterday, and then I did it again just now to make sure. It works without special treatment for a(1). Mathematica is that clever.

Try it out yourself: "a[n_] := n + 1 - a[EulerPhi[n]]; Table[a[n], {n, 1, 20}]". New notebook. I'm using 11.3 on Linux if it makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry, but I get an recursion error. MMA version12.1

Comment: Well that's interesting!

Comment: Scratch what I said about Mathematica being all cute and figuring out the anchor a(1). @DanielHuber is correct, It doesn't. I get a recursion error too. Not sure what I was doing before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good chance to use `#0`:)

```
If[#1 == 1, 1, # + 1 - #0[EulerPhi @ #]] & /@ Range[20]
```

> ```
>  {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 6, 5, 8, 4, 10, 4, 10, 10, 11, 7, 14, 6, 15}
> ```

Make it `Listable`:

```
  Function[, If[#1 == 1, 1, # + 1 - #0[EulerPhi @ #]], Listable] @ Range[20]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 6, 5, 8, 4, 10, 4, 10, 10, 11, 7, 14, 6, 15}
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I've used # before but I've never quite managed to  commit the syntax/semantics to long term memory. I write Matehematic snippets like once a year or so. Any chance you could rewrite that as a 1-liner? Would something like "Function[, If[#1 == 1, 1, # + 1 - #0[EulerPhi @ #]], Listable] @ Range[20]" work?For that OEIS clout. After all, OEIS db columns is all about bytes.

Edit: Holy mother of g*d, it actually worked! :D

Comment: @EmanuelLandeholm, please see the updated versions.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer. Thanks again!

A340265, watch that space...